# Upgrade tfs 2015 with sql server 2012 to tfs 2017 with sql server 2014

Tags: tfs, upgrade

I want to Upgrade TFS 2015 with sql server 2012 to TFS 2017 with sql server 2014. the problem is, all the collection are backuped from TFS 2015 with planed backup , but without detached collections.  now I have already install the tfs 2017 . what should I now proceed,  I got error Upgrade Assisit find the version 2012 is not compitible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for TFS 2017 , the support SQL Server version is *SQL Server 2016* &
*SQL Server 2014*. TFS 2017 will no longer support SQL 2012.

If you want to upgrade a TFS with SQL upgrade. Ordinarily, the first thing is 
 ***backup TFS database - update the SQL server- restore database***  and then proceed to the inplace-upgrade of TFS.

You could take a look at this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/) for the upgrading, it including **In-Place Upgrade** and **Migration based upgrade**.

---

In your case, you could create a new SQL 2014 instance and remapping the TFS databases to new instance, and then upgrading to TFS 2017. Add detail [steps](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/10/22/migrating-team-foundation-server-2013-databases-and-all-databases-in-sharepoint-2013-to-a-new-server/) to remap TFS databases.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices :

1. You uninstall TFS 2017 and reinstall 2015 to restore your TFS from the Tfs_Configuration through the TFS Administration Console, upgrade SQL Server then proceed to the inplace-upgrade of TFS.
2. Upgrade your SQL Server instance to 2014 and upgrade your DB through the TFS Administration Console.